# Cloudformation access a resource that was already created

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Is there a way to get the profileInstance of a role that wasnt created in the current stack ? Lets say I got in my cloudformation the role`s name (passed as a parameter), is there a way to get its profileinstance ?

Something like :

```
{"Fn::GetAtt" : ["MyRoleName", "ArnOfProfileInstance"] }
```

a more general question, can we access a resource that wasnt created in the current stack or through cloudformation at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you know the arn of role, the profile has **known format**. For example:

```
# role
arn:aws:iam::xxxxxx:role/my-role-name

# profile 
arn:aws:iam::xxxxxx:instance-profile/my-role-name
```

Therefore, you can create the **profile arn from the role arn**. For instance:

```
ProflieArn:
  Fn::Sub:
    - "arn:${AWS::Partition}:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:instance-profile/${rolename}"
    - rolename: !Select [1, !Split ['/', !GetAtt MyInstanceRole.Arn] ]
```

Comment: Correct me If I'm wrong but the profile instance isnt created automaticly. Which means when I create a new role, I need to create also a profile instance if I want to grant that role to ec2 node. In my case, the role was created as part of cloudformation a few weeks ago and with it was created the profile. However the profile arn that I got : arn:aws:iam::accoun-id:instance-profile/vpc-profile_name-some_random_strings

Comment: @JeyJ If someone did put a [custom name](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-iam-instanceprofile.html#cfn-iam-instanceprofile-instanceprofilename) on the profile, and not reused the role name as it should be done, then off course you can't get the name of profile from role. Not without a custom resource in cfn.

Comment: The creation of the profile is with the following template, as u can see no custom_name : "MyCusomProfile" : {
      "Type" : "AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile",
      "DeletionPolicy": "Delete",
      "Properties" : {
        "Path" : "/",
        "Roles" : [
          { "Ref" : "MyRoleName" } ]
      }
    },

Comment: @JeyJ Ah I see. If you control this template, you could export the profile's ARN in its outputs, and then import in the other template. Without [a custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html) you won't be able to reverse engineer the profile arn from role arn if they have different names. Sorry.

Comment: Yeah I have control over this template. My point is that someone run this template a long time a go and the role was already created. I want to get the profile of that role but as u saw in the examples, the profile has some random strings in the end.. Any idea why it generates the random strings ? it doesnt uses the format that u mention in the answer.

Comment: @JeyJ Sorry, name  was my mistake. Profile and role names are same in console. So console, makes the name same. Its not automated behavior. Thus if you don't explicitly specify a name in cfn template to be the same as role, it will just create some random profile name :-(

Comment: So basically If I  can set the InstanceName to rolename-profile, I can build the profile name as u mentioned in your original answer right ?

Comment: @JeyJ This is what console is doing exactly. You can confirm that by creating a role for instance. Its profile will be created in the background and will have same name as the role.

Comment: Thank you ! I used the profileInstanceName to use the same name as the role and I used the format u suggested to pass the ProfileARN.